# adding a column to a dataframe using user input pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, user-input

How to add a column using user input in pandas(python). How can the code be amended to achieve this?

```
sel= str(input("would you like to add a new column to df"))
if sel == "yes":
   name=str(input("Name of new column to df"))
   name=[]
   df= df.append(name)
else:
    print("column not added")
```

Comment: Please let us know if any further clarification required on the solutions.  If no further question, please pick a solution that you found best suit your requirement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there! Changed the append to .loc. See below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3]})
sel= str(input("would you like to add a new column to df"))
if sel == "yes":
    name=str(input("Name of new column to df"))
df.loc[:, name] = 'test values'
else:
    print("column not added")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code?

```
import pandas as pd
x=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
column_name=["Column 1","Column 2","Column 3"]
d=input("Would you like to add columns to your dataframe? ")
if d.lower()=="yes":
    new_columns=[]
    c=input("Add any four numbers to your dataframe, add a ',' after each number: ")
    name=input("Name you column: ")
    list1=str(c).split(",")
    for number in list1:
        number=int(number)
        new_columns.append(number)
    column_name.append(name)
    x.append(new_columns)
    df=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=column_name)
    print(df)
else:
    print("No new columns were added.")
    column_name.append("Column 4")
    df=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=column_name)
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

sel= str(input("would you like to add a new column to df"))
if sel == "yes":
   name=str(input("Name of new column to df"))
   if name != '':
       df[name] = np.nan     # init to NaN.  You are freely to change this
       print(f"column {name} succesffuly added")
   else:
       print("Name empty. Column not added")
else:
    print("column not added")
```

This will check if the input name of column is empty string or not.  If empty, column will not be added.  If column name is not empty, the column contents will be initialized to `NaN`.  You can change this initialization value to your preference.  A message will be displayed with the column name successfully added too.